# C - pass reference to pointer to function for malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, memset

I am trying to pass a pointer reference (double) to a function, and inside the function I want to allocate memory to that pointer and fill it up with 10s. In Visual Studio both in x64 and x86 it doesn't fill up the memory with 10s but instead with 0s.
I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

void GetData(double** d) {
    
    *d = malloc(sizeof(double) * 100);
    if (*d == NULL)
        return;

    memset(*d, 10, 100 * sizeof(double));
}

int main(void) {

    double* data;

    GetData(&data);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", data[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `malloc` get a `void**` parameter? No, it **returns** a pointer to allocated memory. C functions have return values for a reason. Use them.

Comment: `memset` fills byte values, it can't be used with doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
memset(*d, 10, 100 * sizeof(double));
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        (*d)[i] = 10.0;
```

[`memset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) fills byte-by-byte. Therefore, instead of each element of that array becoming 10.0, each byte of each element of that array would become 10. So `memset` can't work with doubles.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest minimizing the use of side effects (like modifying pointer parameter referenced objects) and use return vales when possible.

`memset` sets **bytes**. Setting all bytes in the double number to 10 will not set the double value to `10.0`.

```
double *GetData(size_t num) {
    
    double *d = malloc(sizeof(*d) * num);
    if (d)
        for(size_t index = 0; index < num; index++)
            d[index] = 10.0;
    return d;
}

int main(void) {

    double* data = GetData(100);

    for (int i = 0; d && i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```